# Stream uploading file to S3 on Node.js using formidable and (knox or aws-sdk)

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, formidable, knox-amazon-s3-client

I'm trying to stream upload a file submitted via a form directly to an Amazon S3 bucket, using [aws-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) or [knox](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox). Form handling is done with [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable).

My question is: how do I properly use formidable with aws-sdk (or knox) using each of these libraries' latest features for handling streams?

I'm aware that this topic has already been asked here in different flavors, ie:

- [How to receive an uploaded file using node.js formidable library and save it to Amazon S3 using knox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505871/how-to-receive-an-uploaded-file-using-node-js-formidable-library-and-save-it-to)
- [node application stream file upload directly to amazon s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526673/node-application-stream-file-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3)
- [Accessing the raw file stream from a node-formidable file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860449/accessing-the-raw-file-stream-from-a-node-formidable-file-upload) (and its very useful accepted answer on overiding form.onPart())

However, I believe the answers are a bit outdated and/or off topic (ie. CORS support, which I don't wish to use for now for various reasons) and/or, most importantly, make no reference to the latest features from either aws-sdk (see: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/13#issuecomment-16085442) or knox (notably putStream() or its readableStream.pipe(req) variant, [both explained in the doc](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox/blob/master/Readme.md)).

After hours of struggling, I came to the conclusion that I needed some help (disclaimer: I'm quite a newbie with streams).

HTML form:

```
<form action="/uploadPicture" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="picture" type="file" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Express bodyParser middleware is configured this way:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({defer: true}))
```

POST request handler:

```
uploadPicture = (req, res, next) ->
  form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
  form.parse(req)

  form.onPart = (part) ->
    if not part.filename
      # Let formidable handle all non-file parts (fields)
      form.handlePart(part)
    else
      handlePart(part, form.bytesExpected)

  handlePart = (part, fileSize) ->
    # aws-sdk version
    params =
      Bucket: "mybucket"
      Key: part.filename
      ContentLength: fileSize
      Body: part # passing stream object as body parameter

    awsS3client.putObject(params, (err, data) ->
      if err
        console.log err
      else
        console.log data
    )
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> { [RequestTimeout: Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.]
>
> message: 'Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.',
>     code: 'RequestTimeout',
>     name: 'RequestTimeout',
>     statusCode: 400,
>     retryable: false }

A knox version of handlePart() function tailored this way also miserably fails:

```
handlePart = (part, fileSize) ->
  headers =
    "Content-Length": fileSize
    "Content-Type": part.mime
  knoxS3client.putStream(part, part.filename, headers, (err, res) ->
    if err
      console.log err
    else
      console.log res
  )
```

I also get a big res object with a 400 statusCode somewhere.

Region is configured to **eu-west-1** in both case.

Additional notes:

> node 0.10.12
>
> latest formidable from npm (1.0.14)
>
> latest aws-sdk from npm (1.3.1)
>
> latest knox from npm (0.8.3)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, [according to the creator of Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/issues/227), direct streaming to Amazon S3 is impossible :

> The S3 API requires you to provide the size of new files when creating them. This information is not available for multipart/form-data files until they have been fully received. This means streaming is impossible.

Indeed, *form.bytesExpected* refers to the size of the whole form, and not the size of the single file.

The data must therefore either hit the memory or the disk on the server first before being uploaded to S3.

Comment: This is not actually the case. It is possible to pipe/stream to s3! you just need to know the size of the upload. If your client can provide that then you can indeed use pipe to upload to s3 without a nasty hard drive write. 

I'm writing a cli and intermediary server that will upload to s3. Because I control both the client and server I can determine the file size before upload. I think there may be other edge cases like mine that should not be dismissed. I use knox to stream to s3 with a put request.

Comment: @CharlesTWall3 This is a very valid comment, I didn't think about that at the time - I was thinking about a server-side only solution. Feel free to post an answer if you manage to get something working, I'll happily vote for your solution. You may also want to edit this answer. Thanks!

Comment: @CharlesTWall3 - how are you getting on? Can you please post the solution - it might save me 30 mins. Cheers.

Comment: @arcseldon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497404/get-file-size-before-uploading should help. You could start by setting a <input type="hidden" name="file_size"> with the appropriate file size value.

Comment: @gulthor - thanks for your input. For my situation, i was interested in streaming from mongodb via node app (no browser). Found solution by using "s3-upload-stream" NPM module. It uses S3 multipart API and therefore does NOT require the overall filesize up front. It works in chunks and passes their size automatically. Only took a few mins to copy the example code off the readme and plugin to my app. Gotta love the convenience of NodeJS modules community. There are quite few old SOF posts still out there trying to do this using bespoke solutions that are not ideal. Thanks again for suggestion.

Comment: I ended up having to store locally because we needed to zip up the contents when we uploaded. Then unzip on the server before pushing to s3.

Answer (score 13):

Using AWS S3's multipartUpload ([s3-upload-stream](https://github.com/nathanpeck/s3-upload-stream) as working module) and node-formidable's [readable stream](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/commit/d755b423f4f02da10c2f870ccc22f0e3aee35c4e), you can pipe the stream to upload like [this](https://github.com/tsuz/node-formidable/blob/master/example/aws-s3.js):

```
var formidable = require('formidable');
var http = require('http');
var util = require('util');
var AWS      = require('aws-sdk');
var config = require('./config');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: config.get('S3_ACCESS_KEY'),
    secretAccessKey: config.get('S3_SECRET_KEY'),
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01'
});
var s3Stream = require('s3-upload-stream')(s3);
var bucket = 'bucket-name';
var key = 'abcdefgh';


http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    if (req.url == '/upload' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {

        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
            //console.log('onprogress', parseInt( 100 * bytesReceived / bytesExpected ), '%');
        });

        form.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('err',err);
        });

        // This 'end' is for the client to finish uploading
        // upload.on('uploaded') is when the uploading is
        // done on AWS S3
        form.on('end', function() {
            console.log('ended!!!!', arguments);
        });

        form.on('aborted', function() {
            console.log('aborted', arguments);
        });

        form.onPart = function(part) {
            console.log('part',part);
            // part looks like this
            //    {
            //        readable: true,
            //        headers:
            //        {
            //            'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="upload"; filename="00video38.mp4"',
            //            'content-type': 'video/mp4'
            //        },
            //        name: 'upload',
            //            filename: '00video38.mp4',
            //        mime: 'video/mp4',
            //        transferEncoding: 'binary',
            //        transferBuffer: ''
            //    }

            var start = new Date().getTime();
            var upload = s3Stream.upload({
                "Bucket": bucket,
                "Key": part.filename
            });

            // Optional configuration
            //upload.maxPartSize(20971520); // 20 MB
            upload.concurrentParts(5);

            // Handle errors.
            upload.on('error', function (error) {
                console.log('errr',error);
            });
            upload.on('part', function (details) {
                console.log('part',details);
            });
            upload.on('uploaded', function (details) {
                var end = new Date().getTime();
                console.log('it took',end-start);
                console.log('uploaded',details);
            });

            // Maybe you could add compress like
            // part.pipe(compress).pipe(upload)
            part.pipe(upload);
        };

        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
            res.write('received upload:\n\n');
            res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
        });
        return;
    }

    // show a file upload form
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(
        '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
        '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
        '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
        '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
        '</form>'
    );
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: I used this with multiparty

Answer (score 3):

Since this post is so old and I believe streaming directly is now supported, I spent a lot of time reading out of date answers on this topic...

If it helps anyone I was able to stream from the client to s3 directly without the need for installing packages:

https://gist.github.com/mattlockyer/532291b6194f6d9ca40cb82564db9d2a

The server assumes `req` is a stream object, in my case a File object was used in xhr(send) which will send binary data in modern browsers.

```
const fileUploadStream = (req, res) => {
  //get "body" args from header
  const { id, fn } = JSON.parse(req.get('body'));
  const Key = id + '/' + fn; //upload to s3 folder "id" with filename === fn
  const params = {
    Key,
    Bucket: bucketName, //set somewhere
    Body: req, //req is a stream
  };
  s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send('Error Uploading Data: ' + JSON.stringify(err) + '\n' + JSON.stringify(err.stack));
    } else {
      res.send(Key);
    }
  });
};
```

Yes it breaks convention but if you look at the gist it's much cleaner than anything else I found relying on other packages.

+1 for pragmatism and thanks to @SalehenRahman for his help.

Comment: In my case the upload worked, but the image file could not be opened correctly.

Comment: Did you check your extensions? Opened correctly on AWS or from another download? Check that you're receiving the correct amount of bytes too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the 'ContentType' to the Upload params (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property)

```
...
  const params = {
      Key,
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Body: req,
      ContentType: 'image/jpg'
  };
  s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) return err;
      console.log(data);
  });
...
```